# Laravel Auth redirect not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

I am using Laravel v5.2.39. I want to redirect to dashboard only, if you are logged in. If you change URL manually, it will redirect you to home screen. I am using  auth middleware, but it doesn't work. Any help?

My routes.php file:

```
  Route::get('/', function () {
       return view('welcome');
  })->name('home');

     Route::get('dashboard', [
         'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
         'as' => 'dashboard',
         'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);
```

My UserController.php:

```
public function getDashboard(){
   return view('dashboard');
}
```

And auth middleware:

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
             return redirect()->route('home');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

I don't know, whats the problem with. I have some sign in and sign up too, but i dont think this is problem. If somenone wanna see it, write me.

Have a nice day and thank you.

Comment: Would you explain further on the problem you are facing? I dont think its clear enough.

Comment: You apparently want to [do this](http://laravel.io/bin/32lqm) in your routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, have you tried something like this?

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
     Route::get('dashboard', 'UserController@getDashboard')->name('dashboard');
});
```

Or you can add the middleware in the construct function in your class like so :

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

Also, see [the laravel documentation on using middleware with routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes).

Answer (score 0):

Try using  'middleware' => 'auth:web' in place of 'middleware' => 'auth'

Answer (score 0):

Hey im not clear about your problem but this will help you,
when you go for project path `localhost/project/` it will redirect to `localhost/project/home` URL in that URL u can assign any function

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
     return redirect('home');   
 });
```